SQLAlchemy JSONB Comparator Intellisense?
I have started using SQLAlchemy, specifically the flask one, and have had a lot of trouble with the intellisense where most of the time the functions are not listed. (psycopg2)
I found a workaround by doing this:
session: Session = db.session

Where Session is from sqlalchemy.orm. Since both the flask version and sqlalchemy work together it works and I can get the functions listed inside session.
Now I want to use jsonb comparators like has_key, this just doesn't work again.
My class looks like this:
from account import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column


class Account(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test_accounts'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    settings: Mapped[dict|list] = mapped_column(type_=JSONB)

I am using mapping so that I get argument hints as well.
So when I do this:

Account.settings.has_key

has_key is not in yellow text and instead points to sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.
TLDR: I need to use the Comparator for JSONB columns for functions like has_key, but intellisense for it doesn't kick in properly, how can I fix it or use type hints?
